# Help with MySQL my.cnf config

Tags: mysql, configuration

So I'm running MySQL on a high availability cluster with the MySQL data directory on a GlusterFS.

I want to:

```
- Disable the query cache (--query-cache-size=0)

- Switch on external locking (--external-locking=TRUE)

- Disable delays to writing (--delay-key-write=OFF)
```

How would I express these settings in a my.cnf file?

I would like to edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to my taste and then do `service mysql start`

Comment: I notice in the default my.cnf, `query_cache_size=1M` is equivalent to `--query-cache-size=1M`. How do I find out the syntax for these mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to disable query cahche you need add the following prameters to cnf file:

```
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
```

to skip external lock you need to comment or remove `skip-external-locking`

and to disable delay key write you need to add the following parameter

```
delay-key-write= OFF
```